# Prevent batch file from stopping running

Tags: windows, batch-file

I made a script to launch mysql from a batch file, but once the option to start the server is picked, the batch file is prevented from continuing due to executing the file.

How do I make it continue once the command is executed?

The section of code

```
:START
cd "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Server 5.6\bin"
CALL "mysqld" -u y121 -P 3307 &
cls
PAUSE
```

Comment: If mysqld isn't anmother batch use start not call. And insert an additional pair of double quotes to avoid the first being consumed as window title. `start "" "mysqld" -u y121 -P 3307`. The trailing `&` in a batch would mean concatenate the next (not present) command.